# Generate different autonumber for different branches

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently developing a small invoicing system for a company that has many branches. I was wondering how can I generate different invoice autonumbers based on each branch.
Here is my table structure for table `invoice_header`:

```
id | number | cust | grand_total
```

Should I create a different table for each branch? For example `invoice_header_1, invoice_header_2 , invoice_header_3`.

Answer (score 0):

It's nicer and more workable to make a table with the branches types in it.
And then you add only 1 column to the table invoice_header and there you give in the id of the  exact branch from the branch table.

This way you can connect these two and keep it nice and clean. And easier to edit.

So:
table invoice_header
id | number | cust | grand_total | branch_id

table branch
id | branch_name

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ENGINE=MyISAM`, MySQL will do this for you:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_header (
branch_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
number INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
cust INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
grand_total DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

MySQL will generate an unique value for the `id` column, starting at 1, but For each different `branch_id`. This only works if the engine is `MyISAM`.

Search for 'multiple-column index' in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html for more information.